# Can I override the size / power restrictions of the Background Transfer Service on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have an app that needs to be able to download 1GB+ files over a cellular connection on battery power.

I didn't read the documentation properly and implemented a solution using the Background Transfer Service. This works fine for large files with the preference set to 'None', but only when the phone is connected to a power supply.

Does anyone know if there is any way to override this restriction, or know of how I could implement an alternative. If it only works when the app is in the foreground, that will have to do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any file over 100MB needs to go over AC and Wifi as per the current design. There is no way to override these limits unfortunately.

Comment: Thought so. In the end I developed my own download management system! Thanks